# What is the "Content Type" option in survey branching for?

Tags: content-type, survey, settings

When defining branching logic in a SharePoint survey, one of the options in the "Jump To" dropdown is "Content Type".  What is the intended purpose of this option? All I can tell is that if I set it to a choice in the survey, selecting that choice branches to a blank page with just a finish button. I can't find any way to do anything else with Content Types in the survey. I did some searching and the only thing I could find was advice to use it if you want multiple "last questions" depending on earlier branching paths, rather than jumping from the end of those branches to the last question in the survey order. But if that were the intended use of that option, I'd think MS would have named it "end survey" or something instead of "Content Type".

Clicking "Learn about branching" in SharePoint was no help, it just took me to a dumb search page, and the only relevant result for "branching" was the how-to page for creating a survey, which doesn't mention the content type option. I couldn't find any documentation from Microsoft's websites about this either.

Is this a bug, or what am I missing?

Note: I am encountering this in SharePoint 2010.

Answer (score 0):

I did find [this Google Books result](https://books.google.com/books?id=wZJ1l4zXQhwC&pg=PT316&lpg=PT316&dq=%22jump+to%22+%22content+type%22+sharepoint+survey&source=bl&ots=Bzy9tLJfX_&sig=z_ZUgXzW7vuJHOJ7_qlaBTvpdaA&hl=en&sa=X&ei=FMESVf-UOsGXNvuKgfgF&ved=0CCkQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=%22jump%20to%22%20%22content%20type%22%20sharepoint%20survey&f=false) that appears to indicate that the option is extraneous and serves no purpose. (From the link, scroll down slightly to the "An extra option" sidebar.)